# How to expect count bigger or smaller than?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Using `Playwright` and `Python`, how can I expect for count bigger or smaller than?

For example, this code expect for count of 2.

How do I achieve count >= 2 **(Only bigger)**

```
expect(self.page.locator('MyLocator')).to_have_count(2, timeout=20 * 1000)
```

Comment: Exactly what are you testing where you need this type of unusual assertion?

Comment: As per the conditions provided, any value will be true ?

Comment: There are items in the list or table. Their count can be 2 or above, not just count equals to 2.

Comment: "How do I achieve count > 2 or count <=2" as mentioned in the question- this includes any number.

Comment: The request isn't clear but I assume you want `.to_be_greater_than()` and `.to_be_less_than_or_equal_to()` matchers separately, not at the same time. I suggest [edit]ing the post to clarify this, since there is a good deal of confusion in the answers and comments here. That said, I don't think this is possible, so you'll probably need to use a plain non-web-first assertion like `assert page.locator('MyLocator').count() > 2` unless someone comes up with something better using `expect`, or a new matcher is added to the API.

Comment: if xpath is used as locator then it can be used to do the count as `assert page.locator("//ul[count(li) >=2]").count() == 1` or `assert page.locator("//ul[count(li) < 2]").count() == 1`

Comment: I only want bigger, or bigger equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible in the current Python Playwright API, but you could use `wait_for_function` as a workaround:

```py
page.wait_for_function("document.querySelectorAll('.foo').length > 2")
```

This is web-first and will wait for the predicate, but the error message once it throws won't be as clear as the `expect` failure.

If the count is immediately available and you don't need to wait for the predicate to be true, `assert` is useful to mention as another possibility:

```py
assert page.locator(".foo").count() > 2
```

If you're using unittest, you can replace `assert` with, for example

```py
self.assertGreaterEqual(page.locator(".foo").count(), 2)
self.assertGreater(page.locator(".foo").count(), 2)  # or
```

Yet another workaround if you're dealing only with small numbers of elements:

```py
page.locator(".foo")
expect(loc).not_to_have_count(0)
expect(loc).not_to_have_count(1)
expect(loc).not_to_have_count(2)
```

Here, we ensure the count is greater than 2 by process of elimination. It's impossible for count to be less than 0, so we need not include that.

You could do this for less than as well, but not as easily, and using a reasonable assumption that there'll never be more than, say, 20 or 50 elements in any conceivable run:

```py
loc = page.locator(".foo")
for i in range(2, 20):
    expect(loc).not_to_have_count(i)
```

This ensures the count is 0 or 1, or greater than some reasonably high upper-bound.

Comment: self.assertGreaterEqual() does NOT compile in Python. Please update your answer.

Comment: It's part of unittest: [`assertGreaterEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertGreaterEqual), which is built into the standard library.

Comment: And If you use `Pytest`?

Comment: Pytest just uses normal `assert` I think. I don't use the library much. My point wasn't to give a comprehensive overview of greater than assertions in different libraries, just to let you know that you can use an assertion library of your choice and a non-web-first assertion as a workaround, assuming the predicate is immediately available.

Answer (score 6):

Playwright doesn't have options to use bigger/smaller in toHaveCount/to_have_count.

I guess you can rewrite it to Python easily.

```js
const count = await page.locator("MyLocator").count();
expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(2);
expect(count).toBeLessThanOrEqual(2);
```

The only limitation of this approach is that you won't have **expect** retry feature because you check the int value, not a Locator. So you might wanna check for the visibility of the **Locator** first.

```js
const locator = page.locator("MyLocator");
await expect(locator.last()).toBeVisible(); // or first()
const count = await locator.count();
expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(2);
expect(count).toBeLessThanOrEqual(2);
```

Also, PW for NodeJS has [the ability to create custom matches](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend), but I'm not sure it's an option for Python.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to rewrite this in Python Playwright. If there is, can you add that to the answer? As for the JS code here, it's best to use [web-first assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions).

Answer (score 1):

Use [not_to_have_count](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-not-to-have-count)

```
expect(self.page.locator('MyLocator')).not_to_have_count(2, timeout=20 * 1000)
```

Comment: And if count is 0 or 4 - both cases will pass. I need greater or smaller than...

Comment: @TalAngel both 0 and 4 are greater or smaller than 2...

Comment: But I want only greater than 2 Or only smaller than 2. Using your code is guessing.

Comment: As far as I know you will have to implement your own function.

Answer (score -1):

Just found this workaround and it worked like a charm:

> You can do `expect(await locator.count()).toBeGreatedThen()` as a workaround for now. It won't be waiting until the number is greater than, it will just assert it immediately, but it looks like it might work for you."

from https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/8725

Answer (score -2):

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com')  # Replace with your URL
    locator = page.locator('MyLocator')

    # Wait for the element to appear within a timeout
    locator.wait_for_selector(timeout=20000)

    # Get the count of elements matching the locator
    count = locator.count()

    # Check if count is greater than 2 or less than or equal to 2
    if count > 2:
        print(f"Count is greater than 2: {count}")
    elif count <= 2:
        print(f"Count is less than or equal to 2: {count}")

    browser.close()
```

use this and let me have your respect if it works good.
'''ERFAN MOGHIS'''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).